# Lua not instantiating local variable fast enogh to print it? Embeded ESP8266

Tags: lua, esp8266, local-variables, nodemcu

I got an EPS8226 on which I uploaded a `main.lua` file and some other configs. When I run `main.lua` with `dofile()` in the terminal, the `print` from the callback function prints only "sensorId" without "sent 0". Yet, if I run `main.lua` again, or I `print()` something before (either inside the `function()` that calls the callback, or inside the callback itself) it will print properly "sensorId sent 0". This also works if I do not use the `local` variable.

```
function registerReaders()
  for key, value in pairs(sensorConfig.data)
  do
    gpio.mode(value.pin, gpio.INPUT)
    value.timer:alarm(value.polling, tmr.ALARM_AUTO, function() callbacks.sendData(sensorConfig.sensorId[key]) end)
    tmr.create():alarm(1000, tmr.ALARM_SINGLE, function() callbacks.sendData(sensorConfig.sensorId[key]) end)
  end
end
```

Printing "[sensorId_value]"

```
callbacks.sendData = function(sensorId)
  local data = 1
  print(sensorId .. " sent " .. data)
end
```

Printing properly ("OK" then "[sensorId_value] sent 0")

```
 callbacks.sendData = function(sensorId)
      local data = 1
      print("OK")
      print(sensorId .. " sent " .. data)
    end
```

Printing properly ("[sensorId_value] sent 1")

```
callbacks.sendData = function(sensorId)
          print(sensorId .. " sent 0")
        end
```

Comment: What version of the Lua firmware are you using? The latest master version is 2.2

Answer (score 0):

In all examples sensorId is a variable, not a string, so unless sensorId = "sensorId" none of them should be printing "sensorId sent 0".

In the first example (all of them, actually) " sent " is a literal, it should output regardless of the value of data.

Shouldn't the second example print "[...] sent 1"?

Try using a variable name other than data, maybe there's some forward value confusion.

Comment: You are right, I corrected the question to remove confusion. It seems weird that the literal 'sent' is not printed, but that's what happens.

Comment: The one-hit timers are going to fire almost simultaneously and while each registration gets its own anonymous callback function instance, there's only one instance of callbacks.sendData, maybe it's being re-entered? A new instance of the local variable data is created for each call.

Anomalies: 
There's no call to timer:start, how does the callback execute at all?
A parameter is passed to the callback but none is declared. 
You're iterating sensorConfig.data, how is key an index into sensorConfig.sensorId?

Comment: tmr.create():register starts the timer automatically and sets it to fire in 1000ms. This error appears with only one item in the sensorConfig.data.

Comment: If you say so, but according to the docs :start must be called.  I always used tmr.alarm instead, so can't say.  I also manage timers by their id -- you're aware that there are only 6 timers available to user code, correct?

Comment: My bad, I wrote the code instead of copy-paste. Yea, it's alarm.

Comment: Why do you need a one-hit timer to fire 1 sec after registering a repeating timer that calls the same callback?  That seems like problematic design.  Does this occur of you create/start one timer at a time, not in a loop?

Comment: Because the first timer is once every hour, but I also want it to fire at the start of the controller.

Comment: So change the interval the first time it fires.  The timer object that fired is passed to its event callback.  Maybe stagger them when you start them in a loop, add 5 seconds to the interval each iteration.  You only get 6 timers, taking two per iteration is not a conservative use of hardware resources.